# JQuery Datepicker - Restrict datepicker to a specific month and weekdays

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i'm using the following code to restrict date picker to months June to September:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) { 
        monthArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11];
        $("#input_5_5").datepicker({ 
            minDate: 1, 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
             beforeShowDay: function (date) { 
              if ($.inArray(date.getMonth() , monthArray) > -1) {
            return [false, ''];
        }
        function (d) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

It does what i pretended, which is disabling all other months except june to september. Now, i've tried tweaking it so that it would only show specific weekdays using the var 'days' and a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) { 
        monthArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11];
         var days = [2, 4, 6]; 
        $("#input_5_5").datepicker({ 
            minDate: 1, 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
             beforeShowDay: function (date) { 
              if ($.inArray(date.getMonth() , monthArray) > -1) {
            return [false, ''];
        }
        function (d) {
            return [$.inArray(d.getDay(), days) > -1, ''];
        }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

But it's not working. I've tried different ways, but i can't seem to get it to work. Could anyone give me a hand here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Fy9/1012/)**

You can combine the two conditions,

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [$.inArray(date.getDay(), days) > -1 && $.inArray(date.getMonth(), monthArray) > -1]
    }
```

---

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var monthArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11];
    var days = [2, 4, 6];
    $("#input_5_5").datepicker({
        minDate: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            return [$.inArray(date.getDay(), days) > -1 && $.inArray(date.getMonth(), monthArray) > -1]
        }
    });
});
```